# Saving user created list to account

Tags: php, sql, web

I am creating a basic account database-driven PHPp website that lets you create your own groceries list. It already shows the list from the products Table but I'm not sure how I should go about saving the user's list to their accounts so they can see it any time. I was thinking creating a new table for each list but that doesn't sound good. Any ideas?

I have the `users` table with `userid`, `login`, `pw` and `name`. And the `products` table of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As users can have many lists you should create table that stores lists:

Table `Lists` with fields:

```
|id|user_id|list_name|...
```

And next you have to store what products are in a List:

Table `List_Products` with fields:

```
|id|list_id|product_id|
```

Comment: Ok so there should not be a problem with the listproduct table creating 30+ rows just for one list? I will try this as soon as i can. Thanks!